# 'Confusing' probability question, I cannot find any mistake in my working, but my answer is wrong.

Tags: probability

There is this probability problem, I could do the first part, but not the second part. They are very similar but somehow my solution is not correct.

**Problem:** There are 11 cards written the letters E, N, L, A, R, G, E, M, E, N, T with each letter on each card.
Prettie picks a card at random from the 11 cards above and does not replace it.
She then picks a second card at random and does not replace it.

a). Find the probability that she picks two letters that are the same: $\frac{3}{11}\times\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{11}\times\frac{1}{10}=\frac{4}{55}$. This one is correct.

b). Prettie now picks a third card at random. Find the probability that the three letters include exactly two letters that are the same: $\frac{3}{11}\times\frac{2}{10}\times\frac{8}{9}+\frac{2}{11}\times\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{9}{9}=\frac{1}{15}$. And the solution says $\frac{1}{5}$. Somehow for some reasons that I don't understand the reason they multiply $\frac{1}{15}$ by 3.

I could not find any mistake in my working, but I just cannot make sense of the working of the solution. And the solution should be correct, I trust them, but why times 3??

I appreciate any explanations and helps! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us find the probability that there are $2$ E's and $1$ non-E. This can happen in 3 ways, that I will describe as EEX, EXE, and XEE.

You calculated correctly the probability of EEX, that is of E first, then E again, then something else. You will find if you calculate that the probability of EXE is the same as that of EEX, and so is the probability of EEX. So your probability of $2$ E's and $1$ of something else is off by a factor of $3$.

The same thing happens with $2$ N's and $1$ non-N.

This accounts for the fact that the correct answer is $3$ times what you obtained.